# Need For Speed Most Wanted and cross-platform multiplayer

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

Criterion introduced [CloudCompete](http://www.g4tv.com/thefeed/blog/post/726909/need-for-speed-most-wanteds-cloudcompete-system-announced/), a system that keeps track of your stats in the game across platforms. But does it allow multiple platform users to play together?

A friend of mine has already purchased NFS: Most Wanted (2012) on **PS3**. If I buy the same game on **PC**, will I be able to play with him through the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I bought the game for PC and it seems I cannot play with PS3 players. However, I still can see game stats such as times, or game progress.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't count on it. Comparing stats and playing together is something completely different. Actually, I don't know of any game offering this kind of cross-platform gameplay, except the upcoming Dust514 (and even then, you just interact but don't directly play with each other in the same game).

Comment: Shdaowrun allowed x360/PC multiplayer, as well as MMO like DCUO and FFIX. Aside from that, some PS3/Vita allow cross-platform multiplayer (When Vikings Attack and PSASBR, to name a few)

Comment: Interesting, I always thought those MMORPGs had separate servers for consoles. I'd exclude PS3/Vita connections though, as they're still within one vendor's realm (like Gamecube with Gameboy Advance).

Answer (score -1):

Portal 2 does it by automatically making a steam account linked to your psn it's just called psn_yourusername and comes with a free copy of portal 2 for pc via steam download code I played it on ps3 with my friend who was on pc

Comment: He's asking about *Need for Speed: Most Wanted*.  You can't just assume the two games are handled the same way.